# drupal SQL interface module

Tags: drupal

Is there a module out there that would would sort of allow a user to run SQL queries and simple tables to a database directly from Drupal?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/dba . But beware! you are opening a security hole: allowing random database-queries to be ran from your CMS is considerd a severe risk. If correctly configured, however, that hole is not exploitable, but a hole nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

The tablewizard module will allow you to import an arbitraryt table. This cab then be sent to the views module for refining and display. Works very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Module [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) seems like a valid alternative to consider. For more details about Forena, 2 types of documentation are available:

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://www.forenasolutions.org) for an online example of the current:

  - **Forena documentation** - use the link 'Reporting documentation' or visit relative link /reports/help.
  - **Forena samples** - use the link 'Reporting samples' or visit relative link /reports/samples (these samples are fully functional, so make sure to experiment a bit with it, such as the drill downs available on the SVG Graph sample).

The newest 7.x-4.x version also includes an amazing (I think) UI for either creating your reports (the WYSIWYG report editor) and/or for creating your SQL queries (the Query Builder).

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of this module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).